# ¿Cual es el uso de "bobo" en ciertos países?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

En Venezuela significa tonto o una persona que esta como distraída. He escuchado que puede significar otras cosas. Que significa en otros países? O que usos tiene?

Comment: En España significa lo mismo. :)

Comment: Yo también soy español y añadiría que, de las seis acepciones que @EmilioGort lista, yo no entendería ni la acepción 3 ni la 6.

Comment: Aquí otro español que no entendería ni la 3 ni la 6.

Comment: En Perú es frecuente el uso de esa palabra para referirse al corazón o a los relojes de pulsera.

Comment: En El Salvador, por lo menos cuando aún vivía por allá, el significado era idéntico al de Venezuela. Pero comúnmente se usa "baboso", "pasmado" o "dundo" Claro, eso era durante los años 70. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según la RAE

bobo, ba.
(Del lat. balbus, balbuciente).

1. adj. tonto (‖ falto de entendimiento o razón).
2. adj. Extremada y neciamente candoroso. U. t. c. s.
3. adj. coloq. Bien cumplido, no escaso.
4. (Por la facilidad con que se deja atrapar). m. Pez de los ríos de Guatemala y México, de unos 60 cm de longitud y 12 de anchura, de piel negra y sin escamas, carne blanca y con pocas espinas.
5. m. En el teatro español primitivo, personaje cuya simpleza provocaba efectos cómicos.
6. m. Cuba. mona (‖ juego de naipes).

bobo de Coria.

1. m. Personaje proverbial, símbolo de tontería y mentecatez.
   ~ de la yuca.
2. m. y f. coloq. Cuba. Persona tonta, mentecata.

a bobas.

1. loc. adv. ant. neciamente.

   ---

   Soy cubano y generalmente se usa allá para decir tonto pero como un término mucho más suave, que es parecido al sentido que tu dices en tú pregunta.

Comment: ¿Se sigue usando en Cuba con el significado de mona (acepción 6)?

Comment: Cuando era pequeño jugaba un juego de cartas llamado el bobo, que es la descripcion de mona. Lo que si nunca que yo sepa le deciamos mona.

Comment: Eso es interesante! Te sugeriría que añadieses este comentario a la respuesta.

Answer (score 3):

Hay un ave llamada pájaro [bobo](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%A1jaro_bobo). Algunos le llaman así al pingüino (lo cual yo evitaría: los pingüinos son inteligentes).

Answer (score 3):

Hay tambien el reciente sentido ["Burgués bohemio"](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burgu%C3%A9s_bohemio) (bobó) que proviene del francés "***Bo**urgeois **bo**hème*".

Answer (score 1):

Los dominicanos generalmente no decimos `bobo` más bien `tonto` o `pendejo`.

`Pendejo` puede ser ofensivo a veces.

Todo depende de la connotación que se le de y claro, de la confianza que tengas con la persona que hablas.

Comment: Se te agradecería que usaras no sólo un buen formato (como `*la_palabra_sobre_la_que_se_discute*`), sino que mejoraras también tu ortografía. Tienes al menos 5 errores en una respuesta tan corta.